# Which boto or boto3 version for sts.get_session_token?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, boto

Which boto3 version do you prefer for get session token?

I got error while running the python code, my opinion of this kind error usually because wrong version of boto3 function

Here's the code

```
import boto3
import os
boto3.setup_default_session(profile_name='default')
MFA_ARN="xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
Duration=129600 # 36 hours
code = input("Enter the MFA code: " )

output = sts.get_session_token(
        SerialNumber=MFA_ARN,
        DurationSeconds=Duration,
        TokenCode=code
        )
```

Here's the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\NabihBawazir\Downloads\Segmentation_Technical\aws-token\aws-token\aws_token.py", line 20, in <module>
    output = sts.get_session_token(
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\NabihBawazir\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\botocore\client.py", line 530, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\NabihBawazir\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\botocore\client.py", line 964, in _make_api_call
    raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (InvalidClientTokenId) when calling the GetSessionToken operation: The security token included in the request is invalid
```

This kind error usually because wrong version of boto3 function

Comment: "This kind error usually because wrong version of boto3 function" - no, it's because you're providing invalid security credentials, as stated in the error message. Look at the credentials for your profile;